# Split a cell and remove duplicates?

Tags: excel, duplicates, cell, user-defined-functions, vba

I am doing cut sets and path sets for a project for school. I have a LONG list of data similar to the following

```
1 9 9 9 9 9 16

1 9 9 9 9 9 17

1 9 9 9 9 9 15

1 9 9 9 9 9 18

1 9 9 9 9 9 19

1 9 9 9 9 9 20

1 9 9 9 9 9 21

1 9 9 9 9 10 16

1 9 9 9 9 10 17

1 9 9 9 9 10 15

1 9 9 9 9 10 18
```

A few thousand entries, each in a single cell, each number separated by a space. I want to be able to remove the duplicate numbers, in this example, the 9 in order to get:

```
1 9 15

1 9 16

1 9 17

1 9 18

1 9 19

1 9 20

1 9 21
```

How can I do this? Please explain it to me like I'm 5. I don't know anything about VBA or formulas and such. Important to note that some of these may have a value such as:

```
1 11 11 19
```

So removing the '1' is not good, I would need to remove specifically the '11'

Answer (score 3):

Try this User Defined Function.

```
Function RemoveDuplicates(ByVal rng As Range) As String
Dim arr() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim dict
arr = Split(rng.Value, " ")
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
    dict.Item(arr(i)) = ""
Next i
RemoveDuplicates = Join(dict.keys, " ")
End Function
```

Assuming your string is in A2 then you can try the above user defined function like this...

```
=RemoveDuplicates(A2)
```

[image]

Comment: it just says #VALUE! I'm not entirely certain i'm using these functions correctly. I'm just going and inserting a module, copy pasting that in and then in B2 i'm putting =RemoveDuplicates(A2)

Comment: Please refer to this workbook where the code is placed on Module1. https://www.dropbox.com/s/amdakjbhf5xrz5k/RemoveDuplicates.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Even the one I downloaded that you did says #VALUE! on it :(

Comment: Not sure why this is happening at your end. I have added a screenshot in the answer to show how is it used on the sheet and produced the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

It is a User Defined Function UDF to create it Insert a Module and paste the below code

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to open VB editor
2. Click `Insert` , `Module` then paste the code

> ```
> Function Customduplicate(txt As String, Optional delim As String = " ") As String
>     Dim e
>     With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>         .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
>         For Each e In Split(txt, delim)
>             If Trim(e) <> "" And Not .exists(Trim(e)) Then .Add Trim(e), Nothing
>         Next
>         If .Count > 0 Then Customduplicate = Join(.keys, delim)
>     End With
> End Function
> ```

after closing VB editor, you can see the Function in fx
In B1
`=Customduplicate(A1, " ")`
you have to include the delimiter " " one space in the parameters of the Function
A1 is your first Cell
And you can drag it down
You can use this UDF with other delimiters ","